# Getting "last visited field" in a Java Bean

Tags: java, exception, reflection, javabeans

For Exceptionhandling, I want to know, which getter/field in a given Bean produced the Exception. What I do not want is a try/catch around every getter-call, or having to manually keeping track with a String variable.

Can I use Java Reflections for it?
How could I design an Interface the Bean implements?

Pseudo-Code where I want the Exception handling to happen:

```java
try {
            step.setNo(Long.parseLong(stepElement.getChildText("no", nameSpace)));
            step.setName(stepElement.getChildText("name", nameSpace));
            step.setDetail(stepElement.getChildText("detail", nameSpace));
            step.setEcuName(stepElement.getChildText("ecu-name", nameSpace));
}catch(Exception e){
            String fieldname = /*which field did throw? */
}
```

Part of the actual Bean:

```java
public class CupProcStep {
    private long no;
    private String name;
    private String detail;
    private String ecuName;
    private String ecuVariant;
    private String diagnosticsId;
    private String errorText;
    private String stepResult;

public long getNo() {
        return no;
    }

    public void setNo(long no) {
        this.no = no;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public String getEcuName() {
        return ecuName;
    }
```

The name of the field, that threw the Exception, e.g. "no","name,"ecuName", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is almost always the wrong solution.

It's quite easy to store the relevant field name during execution of the code that may throw.

```
String fieldName = "no";
try {
    step.setNo(Long.parseLong(stepElement.getChildText("no", nameSpace)));
    fieldName = "name";
    step.setName(stepElement.getChildText("name", nameSpace));
    fieldName = "detail";
    step.setDetail(stepElement.getChildText("detail", nameSpace));
    fieldName = "ecu-name";
    step.setEcuName(stepElement.getChildText("ecu-name", nameSpace));
} catch (Exception exc) { // Be more specific!
    // fieldName available here
}
```

In this case, we can better make sure we don't make a copy-and-paste error by only writting the field name once.

```
String fieldName = "no";
try {
    step.setNo(Long.parseLong(stepElement.getChildText(fieldName, nameSpace)));
    fieldName = "name";
    step.setName(stepElement.getChildText(fieldName, nameSpace));
    fieldName = "detail";
    step.setDetail(stepElement.getChildText(fieldName, nameSpace));
    fieldName = "ecu-name";
    step.setEcuName(stepElement.getChildText(fieldName, nameSpace));
} catch (Exception exc) { // Be more specific!
    // fieldName available here
}
```

Some would place the assignment within the method call (`getChildText(fieldName = "ecu-name",`), but I'm not a fan of side-effects in subexpressions.

The whole `stepElement.getChildText(fieldName, nameSpace)` is repeated code, and probably repeated for other types. Factoring this out into a class is left as an exercise. The `try-catch` part can be factored out using the Execute Around idiom. This would end up with client code looking like:

```
someObject.someFunction(element -> {
    step.setNo(Long.parseLong(element.get("no")));
    step.setName(element.get("name"));
    step.setDetail(element.get("detail"));
    step.setEcuName(element.get("ecu-name"));
});
```

Or, I guess:

```
someObject
    .get("no",       step::setNo, Long::parseLong)
    .get("name",     step::setName)
    .get("detail",   step::setDetail)
    .get("ecu-name", step::setEcuName);
```

There are ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) libraries, such as JAXB, available for certain types of format, but they become a surprisingly large project - use an existing implementation if you can (unless you particularly want to shave that yak).

Comment: Exactly this is what I meant with "having to manually keeping track with a String variable.". Thats not what I want. I want some automation, because manually doing so is errorprone.